# Good way to reverse proxy through a forward proxy

Tags: proxy, http, reverse-proxy

I have an app that uses HTTP to connect to a server but does not support using an HTTP proxy and I must use an HTTP proxy to get to the server.

I would like to set up a reverse proxy service (it's on a Linux server) that can go through the regular proxy server.

So:

```
App --> Reverse Proxy ----------> Forward Proxy -------------> Server
|====Localhost=======|   Net      |=Somewhere=|     Net   |=Somewhere Else=|
```

I've looked at a couple of lightweight reverse proxys but they don't support forwarding through a proxy server. I'd prefer not to run something heavy like apache or squid but if they are the only things that would work, they would do. (Although from apaches docs, it doesn't look like it would work either.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If your forward proxy server supports transparent proxying, you can just use iptables to redirect HTTP traffic transparently to your forward proxy.

Otherwise, you need to install a proxy server as you described and configure your application to use it as if it is the real server.

Comment: I have no control over the proxy server. I am looking for software that is preferably lightweight (like tinyproxy), and supports reverse proxying through a forward proxy (Much of the proxy software out there does not support chaining and reverse proxy mode at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

[Squid-cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/) should be able to do this. Look at the "never-direct" settings for configuring it so requests go through a parent instead of directly out. Also check out [Apache Traffic Server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/). It claims to do just about anything! I think the config file is icp.config.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.